# Making these Term Equal / In Terms Of

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, number-theory, numerical-methods

Here is my question:

```
30x + 15

19x + 95
```

Ok, in this question, x is infinite but my main question is what would the second expression be if x's value was in terms of 30x? Not proportionate, equal.

I tried balancing the expression but when I got the end result it didn’t make sense since the first expression was originally bigger than the second one and plus were trying to make it in terms of 30x, not proportionate.

Is there a way to represent the change in x through the value of the right of the expression? I don't know but hopefully you can understand where I’m getting at.

Thank you though.

Comment: You keep mentioning *equation* but I see none.  I do see two expressions, though.  Are you wanting to do something with the equation $30x + 15 = 19x + 95$, which is setting the two expressions equal?

Comment: I aplogise, it is supposed to be expressions not equations. I'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

"My main question is what would the second expression be if $x$'s value was in terms of $30x$? Not proportionate, equal."

I suppose you mean what the second expression is if the two expressions should be equal, i.e. what the value of $x$ is for the two expressions to be equal

$30x + 15 = 19x + 95$

$30x + 15 -19x= 19x + 95 - 19x$

$11x + 15 = 95$

$11x + 15 -15 = 95 -15$

$11x = 80$

$\frac{11x}{11} = \frac{80}{11}$

$x = \frac{80}{11}$

$x = \frac{80}{11} \approx 7.27$